# Angular 2 Sort table columns

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to sort my columns of my table using Angular 2

the pipe transform code is

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({  name: 'orderBy' })
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(records: Array<any>, args?: any): any {

    return records.sort(function(a, b){
      if(a[args.property] < b[args.property]){
        return -1 * args.direction;
      }
      else if( a[args.property] > b[args.property]){
        return 1 * args.direction;
      }
      else{
        return 0;
      }
    });
  };
}
```

I have defined a sort function in component.ts file as following as :

```
  sort(property){
    this.isDesc = !this.isDesc; //change the direction
    this.column = property;
    this.direction = this.isDesc ? 1 : -1;
    //this.sort(this.column);
  };
```

**HTML looks like this**

```
 <th class="cell-width-header title" (click)="sort(sellerNo)">
            Seller No
            <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-sort': column != 'sellerNo', 'fa-sort-asc': (column == 'sellerNo' && isDesc), 'fa-sort-desc': (column == 'sellerNo' && !isDesc) }" aria-hidden="true"> </i>
          </th>




 <tr *ngFor="let x of selectedData  | orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction}">


            <td>{{x.sellerNo}}</td>
```

but after loading the page, I get following error

zone.js:522 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./FundingRequestComponent class FundingRequestComponent - inline template:208:14 caused by: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: 
    ViewWrappedError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Error in ./FundingRequestComponent class FundingRequestComponent - inline template:208:14 cau……}
     Error: Error in ./FundingRequestComponent class FundingRequestComponent - inline template:208:14 caused by: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined
        at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:6688:33)
        at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:94913:16)
        at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:94978:16)
        at new ViewWrappedError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:96282:16)

Comment: What is selectedData's type?

Comment: It is  JSON, coming from backend service

Comment: what is sellerNo? a variable in your .ts file? If not, I suppose that the name of the property you want so sort by. Wrapp it in ''

Comment: And the only place where you are calling .sort in an object is in the pipe. Most likely selectedData is null/undefined when you call the pipe....

Comment: @Jota.Toledo seller no is the name of the column and an element in my json data that I am filtering

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are loading the data (`selectedData`) for this template asynchronously in the component's class, so at the start it's not yet returned form the service, hence `selectedData = undefined`.

There are several things you can do to mitigate that:

#### 1. Initialize the data in the component

Set the `selectedData` class property to an empty array so when the pipe runs its input will be an array even if the backend data is not yet returned.

```
export class MyComponent {
    selectedData = [];
}
```

#### 2. Prevent evaluation of this part of the template with `*ngIf`

Don't render the template part with said pipe until you have the array.

```
<table *ngIf="selectedData">
  <!-- ... -->
  <tr *ngFor="let x of selectedData  | orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction}">
</table>
```

#### 3. Make the pipe "empty-input-safe" by providing a default input

This should be the preferred solution because with that you won't have to remember to employ any special logic (like *ver. 1* or *ver. 2*) each time you're using this pipe somewhere.

```
@Pipe({  name: 'orderBy' })
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(records: Array<any> = [], args?: any): any {
    /* ... */
```

See the `records = []` default in the `transform`'s method parameter?

I try to use this as a general rule of thumb to **always prepare the pipe for getting no input initially**. Makes a lot of headaches go away :)

Comment: is there a way i could implement this with 3 columns that i can choose from?